# `code` Корректный код, но внешне отображается некорректно во всех браузерах

Tags: инспекция-кода, браузер

На всех сайтах и во всех браузерах `code` отображается как на рисунке. В чём может быть причина, уже всё перешерстил. Если подумать логически, может дело в компьютере?
[image: Внешний вид]

Comment: Может, что-то с настройкой шрифтов в системе? Это Windows?

Comment: Да, Win10. Шрифты тоже смотрел, всё как обычно.